# Is necessary to restart Server/PC while installing the sharepoint server 2013

Tags: 2013, installation

I am new to SharePoint. I want to install SharePoint Server 2013 on my production server.

I want to know during the installation of SharePoint 2013 , a server restart is required or not.

Let know step by step installation of SharePoint server 2013.

Comment: On your production server? Without attempting first on a non-production to find out first? Do a bit of homework, you will more than likely break your production environment if you try to install SP2013 with zero planning or prior knowledge of the platform.

Answer (score 0):

it is quite exustif list when install sharepoint. Here is a good [link](http://www.sharepointassist.com/2012/08/04/sharepoint-2013-lab-build-part-1-getting-started/) to follow t see it step by step. I will provide you with check list to follow to be sure you are not forget anything. This is full but not complete list:

   Before Windows Server installation chose a type of disk to create

   Dynamic – size max is specified but no space is allocated. Advised size is 100GB for DEV purposes.

   Fixed – size is allocated directly event if space is not used.

   SELECTED SIZE:

   Before installing SharePoint, update windows to the latest version installing all updates

   Install Windows hot fix updates: KB2554876 and KB2472264. This should be done, before SharePoint is installed. These updates are required cause of usage of Windows Server 2008R2 instead of advised Windows Server 2012

   Add “Active Directory Domain” role to server

   Launch dcpromo.exe to create and configure DNS server

   When create a forest the name should be different from desired cause when change to machine name this will give double naming. E.g. Forest name SP2013.local. When change machine name to SP2013 this gives SP2013.SP2013.local. In this case machine name should be different to avoid name doubling: DEV for example – DEV.SP2013.local

   SELECTED FOREST NAME:

   Forest functional level: Windows Server 2008R2

   Rename machine

   SELECTED MACHINE NAME:

   AD accounts should be created (ref. User Accounts)

   Install SQL server

   Add only database engine feature and Basic management tools feature. This is enough for SP installation and development process.

   Add SQL_Service and SP_Farm accounts as Server administrators to SQL to add it as a SQL administrators; this will give flexibility and will avoid unnecessary adding each time database is created…

   When install SQL change collation to Latin_General_100 with CI_AS_KS_WS (Case-insensitive, Accent sensitive, kana sensitive, width sensitive).

   Enable file stream to be able to read blob files as a streaming to not to download a file once but get it by parts (e.g. You tube seek video – get from position)

   In DNS server console add forwarded lookup zone of “A” type with name of the server to call (desired one) and IP to local host (127.0.0.1).

   Change listen default port for SQL server

   TCP/IP protocol should be enabled.

   Create SQL Server client aliases on all front-end web servers and application servers in the farm.

   Create this for both 64 and 32 bits. 32 bits is required for SQL Management studio being connected to SQL server using this alias.

   SELECTED SQL Server Alias:

   When set alias set as server specified in DNS forwarded zone one.

   Create X.udl file to test connection of the server.

   Add inbound exception to Fire Wall for new port to listen

   Install Service pack for SQL as it is requirement for SharePoint 2013

   In SQL Management Studio set RAM usage by SQL Server. Advised is 50% of 
available… Try to connect using alias to test connection to the server.

   SELECTED AMMOUNT OF RAM:

   In Server Management Studio set MAXDOP value

   Set recovery mode (optional):

   Set auto growth value (optional):

   Install Prerequisites for SharePoint 2013

   Install next updates KB2708075 and KB2759112.

   Start installing SharePoint 2013

   Specify SP_Farm account as “Database Access Account”

   Add SP_Services as managed user account

   Add SP_Search as managed user account

   Add SP_SuperUser as managed user account

   Add SP_WebApps as managed user account

   Start services that have to be configured

   Configure services

   Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service (Default started)

   Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application (Default started)

   Central Administration (Default started)

   Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming E-Mail (Default started)

   Distributed Cache (Default started)

   Secure Store Service

   User Profile Service

   Managed Metadata Web Service

   Search Host Controller Service

   SharePoint Server Search (Started after search service is created)

   Create new Search Service Application

   Search Query and Site Settings Service (Started after search service is created)

   Business Data Connectivity Service

   Machine Translation Service

   Configure Service Applications

   MMS

   Translation service

   Create site

   Create web Application

   Create site collection

   Configure server for development

   Disable loopback check

   Add entry for site in host file

   Add IIS bindings for the site

   Restart server