# Virtual machine in SharePoint 2010 development

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

What is the best practice to set up development environment of SharePoint 2010 through 5 virtual machine. How to configure same settings in each machine and to update code in source control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what VM do you use? I'm using Virtual Box of Oracle and it works quite well. YOu can create as many VMs as you wish but it will cost you in a lots of RAM on your machine.

For my development purposes I have 24GB of RAM and three-tier farm with:

1. Front-end (4GB)
2. Application services (4GB)
3. Database server (50% of all avalable PC RAM - in my case it is 8GB)

Rest of RAM is used by my host PC.

For best practices there is MS deployment guide which is very usefull when follow it. You can find it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10009).

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Comment: Best practice I mean here is what SP leads practically follow for successful project delivery. Not what MS recommended. I needed your own approach.

Comment: you mean that your development machine has 24 GB RAM... quite high specs

Comment: I had to upgrade to host SP2013 VMs that is why so much of RAM. 

For the best is to try to make a farm which will be most of all similar to production environment. I know it is hard to do this when limited to DEV. 

From my own experience, when develop in standalone mode there is always problems on PROD side. If you are quite limited in hardware install SQL, SharePoint and application services on the same machine but as separated installations: using local domain, SQL server (which can be easily moved to another server – VM), SharePoint which will serve as front-end server.

Comment: any good link which resemble your setup?

Comment: Hi, here is my big answer with check list how to install SP2013 VM but it can be applied to SP2010 as well: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62839/is-necessary-to-restart-server-pc-while-installing-the-sharepoint-server-2013/62855#62855. Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 1):

You could possible make all major configurations in one virtual machine, and then copy that harddrive file (.vhd-file in Hyper-V) and use it as the base for the other virtual machines.

(By pasting the .vhd in new folders for each machine, and then create new virtual machine from existing harddrive, [Link](http://www.petri.co.il/windows-8-client-hyper-v-part-4-create-a-virtual-machine-based-on-an-exisiting-vhd-file.htm))

Regarding Source control, there are a number of tools for integrating source control with Visual Studio, like [ankh SVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) and Microsofts [TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff637362.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In my team what we usually do when we have a new project is create a Base SharePoint Image. This image will then be provided to the different developers that will be added in the project. The base SharePoint image we have is usually done with the following steps:

1. Installing the OS of your choice
2. Updating the configuration of the server so that

   - the shutdown tracker is removed
   - Updating the machine name
   - Enable the remote desktop connection
   - Disable IEEC
3. After that we typically the AD services and create a new forest for the server
4. Install Visual Studio
5. Install Office Client if needed
6. Install SharePoint Designer
7. Install SQL Server
8. Install SharePoint
9. Install all other items needed for the project (3rd party tools)

Once this is done each developer will be provided the same copy of this image so that all of us will have the same setup. As for the source control just setup an SVN or a TFS and connect your visual studio there.

Comment: My question is how to update TFS from each VM equivalent to each individual user. What strategy I should follow? Your guidance needed.

Comment: What is the process of updating content database in each virtual machine at par with each other, so that for each user DB will be same? In what frequency update should be done.

Comment: I got confused with the TFS question. Can you please rephrase it? As for the content database, you can just setup a separate database server instead of having SQL server installed in your virtual machines so that everyone will be working on the exact same data.

Comment: Do you mean your approach is to 

Develop on Network VM – Centralized Server Virtualization?

Or 

Develop on Local VM – Desktop Virtualization on Windows 7 x64

Pl clarify...

Can you pl elaborate on the whole setup so that how each developer can update TFs and how to build & test from TFS ultimately.

Can u pl send any good link what you follow?

Comment: Our approach is to develop on local VMs and use an integration server VM for integration of all items prior to deployment to QA or Production.

Comment: I have updated my question...

Comment: Basically we have 5 individual VMs and each VM is connected to our centralized TFS Server and Database Server.

Comment: In this case how is "integration server VM" is placed in between TFS & database server?

Comment: Integration Server VM doesn't have any connection to TFS but has it's own database server. Basically it is where we deploy/transfer all our solution to integrate everything once we confirm that everything is working locally on our end. The Integration Server setup should be similar to the setup of your production and QA server to ensure same scenario in your environment.

Comment: In that case how is TFS client connected exactly? I mean where is TFS client with Visual studio placed?

Answer (score 0):

You can find best practices here,

[Setting Up the Development Environment for SharePoint 2010 on Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Here's recommended topologies by Microsoft,

[SharePoint 2010 topologies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199%28v=office.14%29.aspx)